# Text not showing up in production React Native app

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I just released my first React Native app in the Google Play store, and discovered that none of the text is visible on my device. Here's how it looks on my emulator (Pixel 2), and on my Pixel 7.[image: Emulator]

[image: Pixel 7 Production]

I tried reinstalling the app, but that didn't seem to work. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you defined the text colour? What about the theme in your devices: dark or light?

Comment: It looks like changing the theme to 'Light Mode' on my device fixed it. I'll add support for Dark Mode, thank you so much!